# How do I convert a String to an InputStream in Java?

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, inputstream

Given a string:

```
String exampleString = "example";
```

How do I convert it to an `InputStream`?

Comment: InputStreams look at bytes, Readers look at characters.

Answer (score 1624, accepted):

Like this:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(exampleString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Note that this assumes that you want an InputStream that is a stream of bytes that represent your original string encoded as *UTF-8*.

For versions of Java less than 7, replace `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` with `"UTF-8"`.

Comment: Doesn't this charset get lost when doing: String --> bytes --> ByteArrayInputStream ? When trying this on a for example "ü", the bytes will have the right letter, but the ByteArrayInputStream will have lost the right conversion. Or am I wrong?

Comment: StandardCharsets requires minimum API level 19.

Comment: @JonathanRamos it's not up to the stream to hold the conversion. It's up to whatever is decoding the bytes back into strings.

Comment: @Nantoka Instead of StandardCharsets.UTF_8 you can use Charset.forName("UTF-8") for any API Level.

Comment: for okhttp3 users: don't use this approach, it will broke your images that should be displayed on webview.  just use :  response.body().byteStream()    `byteStream()` method.

Comment: Not pretty if you have large string objects and want to save on memory/allocations. A proper streaming solution would be nice.

Answer (score 292):

I find that using [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) makes my life much easier.

```
String source = "This is the source of my input stream";
InputStream in = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toInputStream(source, "UTF-8");
```

You may find that the library also offer many other shortcuts to commonly done tasks that you may be able to use in your project.

Comment: They used new ByteArrayInputStream(exampleString.getBytes("UTF-8")). So it will be optimized way to use InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(exampleString.getBytes("UTF-8"));

Comment: @PankajKumar: Java's JIT compiler is more than able to inline this.

Comment: Using a method which doesn't specify encoding is a terrible idea...

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy: Apache commons includes another form of this method which takes the encoding as a second parameter (which, you're right, is preferable): InputStream in = IOUtils.toInputStream(source, "UTF-8");

Comment: You can use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` definition instead of plain text.

Comment: Why is "Using a method which doesn't specify encoding is a terrible idea..."?

Comment: Careful, that one causes a crash on Android 7 as `ThreadLocal.withInitial` is not available before API26.

Answer (score 44):

You could use a [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) and convert the reader to an input stream using the solution in [this other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62241/how-to-convert-a-reader-to-inputstream-and-a-writer-to-outputstream).

Answer (score 18):

There are two ways we can convert String to InputStream in Java,

1. Using ByteArrayInputStream

Example :-

```
String str = "String contents";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

2. Using Apache Commons IO

Example:-

```
String str = "String contents"
InputStream is = IOUtils.toInputStream(str, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Hi @anil do you have opinion /experience which one is better?

Comment: my opinion, using Apache commons IO is better option

Answer (score 0):

You can try [cactoos](https://github.com/yegor256/cactoos/) for that.

```
final InputStream input = new InputStreamOf("example");
```

The object is created with `new` and not a static method for [a reason](https://www.yegor256.com/2017/11/14/static-factory-methods.html).