# How can I read a String into an inputStream in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert a String to an InputStream in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782178/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-inputstream-in-java)

How can I read a String into an InputStream in Java ?

I want to be able to convert `String say = "say"` into an InputStream/InputSource. How do I do that?

Comment: This is pretty well documented if you just google it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class StringToInputStreamExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "This is a String ~ GoGoGo";

    // convert String into InputStream
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());

    // read it with BufferedReader
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    br.close();
   }
}
```

Source: [How To Convert String To InputStream In Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-inputstream-in-java/)

Comment: +1 Nice use of the reader :)

Comment: -1 for not specifying a `Charset` in `str.getBytes()`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like...

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(sValue.getBytes());
```

Should work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ByteArrayInputStream`. It reads elements from a `byte[]` with the `InputStream` methods.

Answer (score 0):

For an `InputStream` MadProgrammer has the answer.

If a `Reader` is ok, then you could use:

```
Reader r = StringReader(say);
```