# How to convert a String[] array to InputStream in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, inputstream

I have a `String[]` array and I need to convert it to `InputStream`.

I've seen `Byte[]` -> `InputStream` and `String` -> `InputStream`, but not this. Any tips?

Comment: An InputStream of what? Delimited? Length-prefixed?

Comment: An InputStream is for binary, perhaps you wanted a Reader which is for text?

Comment: Actually, either will do, but I arbitrarily chose to ask about InputStream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can construct a merged `String` with some separator and then to `byte[]` and then to `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Here's a way to [convert a String to InputStream in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782178/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-inputstream-in-java).

Comment: Yeah... that's the way I was going to go... zip up an array of newlines with my string array and join to a string... but I was hoping there was a more direct route.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the following link: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-inputstream-in-java/

However, the difference in the code is that you should concatenate all the strings together in one string before converting.

```
 String concatenatedString = ... convert your array

        // convert String into InputStream
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());

        // read it with BufferedReader
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        br.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

There is still no single method call to do this but with Java 8 you can do it in a single line of code. Given an array of String objects:

```
    String[] strings = {"string1", "string2", "string3"};
```

You can convert the String array to an InputStream using:

```
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(String.join(System.lineSeparator(), Arrays.asList(strings)).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```