# Make Scanner read a String in java

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I am converting command line java application to swing GUI. I have a Parser class that reads input from Scanner

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
command = in.nextInt();
```

Is it possible to pass String instead of (System.in) ? Or, is there a better way to deal?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782178/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-inputstream-in-java

Comment: Or better yet, look at the docs. Short answer is: yes. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nextLine()` of Scanner class to read string value entered in console.

Below is an example:

```
 public class Parser {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter command:");
    String command = in.nextLine();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, command);

}

}
```

**Eneter string value in console:**

```
Please enter command:
Java Command
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want pass Strings in Scanner just use Java's `next()` method

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String command = in.next();
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.