# Loading an ontology from string using OWL API

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

Is there a way to load an ontology from string using OWL API?

Comment: From a string you can get a ByteArrayInputStream, so if you can load from an input stream, you can load from a string.

Comment: E.g., see [How do I convert a String to an InputStream in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/782178/1281433)

Comment: Then you can use the method [loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(InputStream)](http://goo.gl/F7KGzF).

Comment: There it tries to create an IRI from which the document can be read.

Comment: No, I didn't mean load from the string.  I mean create a bytearrayinputstream from the string, and then load the ontology from the input stream with loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument.