# Parse json file to javax.json library

Tags: java, json

Trying to use `javax.json` to read some `json` data. Currently I have no issues to read the file this way(exception handling skipped):

```
FileInputStream json =  new FileInputStream("testJSON.json");
JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(json);
```

This works fine when I have a seperate `json` file, in this case it is `testJSON.json`. Now what I want to do is simply parse in the `json` string, instead of the `json` file. For example, I have a `json` string that looks like this:

```
[{"Gross Weight":"12","Tare Weight":"3","Price Per Pound":"2"},{"Gross Weight":"123","Tare Weight":"32","Price Per Pound":"23"}]
```

Is it possible to parse this `json` data to the `JsonParser`? Or any other Java library can handle this request?

Comment: You can convert your `String` instance to an `InputStream`: see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/782183/1076463)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.io.StringReader in = new java.io.StringReader(theString);
JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(in);
```

Please study the Javadocs of the libaries you are using from time to time.

Comment: `String jsonString = "[{"Gross Weight":"12","Tare Weight":"3","Price Per Pound":"2"},{"Gross Weight":"123","Tare Weight":"32","Price Per Pound":"23"}]";` When I do this I got syntax errors, what should I do to make the error go away?

Comment: Java uses `"` as delimiter for string literals. If you want to write a string literal which contains `"` you need to escape it as `\"`, e.g. `jsonString = "[{\"Gross Weight\":\"12\".... ";`