# Consume JSON / Base64 encoded file in Android / Java

Tags: java, android, json, http, inputstream

I have a web service capable of returning PDF files in two ways:

**RAW**: The file is simply included in the response body. For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/pdf

<file_contents>
```

**JSON**: The file is encoded (Base 64) and served as a JSON with the following structure:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "base64": <file_contents_base64>
}
```

I want to be able to consume both services on `Android` / `Java` by using the following architecture:

```
// Get response body input stream (OUT OF THE SCOPE OF THIS QUESTION)
InputStream bodyStream = getResponseBodyInputStream();

// Get PDF file contents input stream from body stream
InputStream fileStream = getPDFFileContentsInputStream(bodyStream);

// Write stream to a local file (OUT OF THE SCOPE OF THIS QUESTION)
saveToFile(fileStream);
```

For the first case (**RAW** response), the response body will the file itself. This means that the `getPDFFileContentsInputStream(InputStream)` method implementation is trivial:

```
@NonNull InputStream getPDFFileContentsInputStream(@NonNull InputStream bodyStream) {
    // Return the input
    return bodyStream;
}
```

The question is: **how to implement the `getPDFFileContentsInputStream(InputStream)` method for the second case (JSON response)?**

Comment: `byte[] encodedBytes = json.getBytes("base64"); byte[] decodedBytes = (new BASE64Decoder()).decodeBuffer(encodedBytes); return new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes ); `

Comment: check my (edited) comment in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any json parser (like Jackson or Gson), and then use `Base64InputStream` from apache-commons codec.

**EDIT:** You can obtain an input stream from string using `ByteArrayInputStream`, i.e.

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(exampleString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/782183/7491770).

**EDIT 2:** This will cause 2 pass over the data, and if the file is big, you might have memory problems. To solve it, <strike>you can use Jackson and parse the content yourself like [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/) example instead of obtaining the whole object through reflection.</strike> you can wrap original input stream in another one, say `ExtractingInputStream`, and this will skip the data in the underlying input stream until the encoded part. Then you can wrap this `ExtractingInputStream` instance in a `Base64InputStream`. A simple algorithm to skip unnecessary parts would be like this: In the constructor of `ExtractingInputStream`, skip until you have read three quotation marks. In read method, return what underlying stream returns except return -1 if the underlying stream returns quotation mark, which corresponds to the end of base 64 encoded data.

Comment: Cool! But how can I get an `InputStream` that emits the value of the "base64" key from the JSON so I can wrap it in a `Base64InputStream`?

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer. The thing is: I don't wan't to parse the JSON stream by getting the *base64* value as an object (String). The PDF files can be big (+10MB without base64 encoding), which can potentially consume more memory than the devices can offer. From what I know, neither `JsonReader` (Gson) or `JsonParser` (Jackson) have a method to get a value as an `InputStream` instead of a `String`

Comment: Did you check the example in edit 2? `JsonParser` class of `Jackson` has a method called `getInputSource`, which is a "Method that can be used to get access to object that is used to access input being parsed; this is usually either InputStream or Reader, depending on what parser was constructed with", according to their [doc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html). If you still have further help, I may need to write the method completely. Try yourself, if you cannot, I will help.

Comment: I would be glad if you could write the method implementation so I can accept your answer

Comment: @GabrielHuff is your structure static?

Comment: It can be. I guess this is not relevant in this case.

Comment: @GabrielHuff You can wrap original input stream in another one, say `ExtractingInputStream`, and this will skip the data in underlying input stream until the encoded part. Then you can wrap this `ExtractingInputStream` instance in a `Base64InputStream`.

Comment: Yeah, I got the part about the `Base64InputStream`, it should definitely work. The challenge here is how to get the `ExtractingInputStream`, i.e. how to 'isolate' the file base 64 string from the JSON. Feel free to post a code snippet if you have any idea.

Comment: Writing from mobile, sorry... In the constructor of extracting input stream, skip until you have read three quotation marks. In read method, return what underlying stream returns except return -1 if the underlying stream returns quotation mark. That's all.

Comment: Alright, this should work. I'll accept your answer. I would appreciate if you update your answer whenever you have time so that people can quickly see your solution. Cheers!