# JAVA, NodeSet into XML, parse it to push it in a tree

Tags: java, xml, tree, xml-parsing, vaadin

I am using a framework: vaadin, I have a `NodeSet data;`  and I use it like that: `data.toXMLString();` I get all the XML so no problem with this. But I want to parse `data.toXMLString();` to push all the information into a tree. I watched a lot of forums, conversations in stackoverflow/openclassroom and others but each time the XML is a file, and it doesn't works with mine. Here what I started to do :

```
private void getData(NodeSet data){
            final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try{
                final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                final Document document = builder.parse(data.toXMLString());
                final Element racine = document.getDocumentElement();
                System.out.print(racine.getNodeName());

                final NodeList racineNoeuds = racine.getChildNodes();
                final int nbRacineNoeuds = racineNoeuds.getLength();
                for(int i = 0; i < nbRacineNoeuds; i++){
                    if(racineNoeuds.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        final Element child = (Element) racineNoeuds.item(i);
                    }
                }
            } catch (final ParserConfigurationException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final SAXException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tree.addItem(data.toXMLString());
        }
```

I don't finish it because when I launch my server I have this error :

> java.net.MalformedURLException

at this line : `final Document document = builder.parse(data.toXMLString());`

So if you have any idea.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of the `builder.parse(...)`is incorrect.
According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) passing a string as argument, means you provide a URL to retrieve the document from.

You will need to convert your String into a InputStream before passing it to the method.
See in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782178/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-inputstream-in-java) how to do it.