# Convert String to InputStream in Groovy

Tags: string, groovy, inputstream

Given a string:

```
String xml = "<test/>";
```

How do I convert it to an `InputStream` in Groovy?

Currently I use:

```
IOUtils.toInputStream(xml, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

It works, but I'm looking for some shorter and dependency-free way of doing that in Groovy.

Of course I know [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782178/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-inputstream-in-java) for Java, but it involves ugly creation of `ByteArrayInputStream`. I'm looking for GDK way of solving that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a String to an InputStream in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782178/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-inputstream-in-java)

Comment: `IOUtils.toInputStream()` does exactly `new ByteArrayInputStream()` stuff. GDK does not add any method similar to `InputStream.getText()` that converts String to InputStream. Actually doing it with `ByteArrayInputStream` is the easiest and straightest way.

Answer (score 15):

Has not much to do with Groovy, plain java:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream( xml.getBytes( 'UTF-8' ) )
```

Comment: Groovy has `text` method to convert `InputStream` to `String`, so I'm looking for similar shorthand the other way round without `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: That takes a byte array and not a stream.

Comment: why would it take a stream, if the OP requested a String?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.StringResource` on classpath it becomes just:

```
new StringResource(xml).inputStream
```

It is included in cglib, so if you do mocking, probably you can use above shorthand in tests.