# How to replace StringBufferInputStream with StringReader?

Tags: java, stringreader

Using JNLP, I have this line :

```
File_Save_Service.saveFileDialog(null,null,new StringBufferInputStream("testing"),null);
```

How to replace StringBufferInputStream with StringReader in this line ? The API for StringBufferInputStream says better use StringReader, but how to convert between different types ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

FileSaveService.saveFileDialog takes an InputStream, not a Reader (because it wants binary data, not character data).

StringBufferInputStream is deprecated because it does not convert characters into bytes properly.

You can use ByteArrayInputStream instead:

```
new ByteArrayInputStream("the string".getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

Comment: The key point is the InputStream needs to know how to encode your bytes.

Comment: Yes, you need to pick an encoding (UTF-8 in the example above).

Comment: In Kotlin, use `toByteArray()` instead of `getBytes("UTF-8")` https://stackoverflow.com/a/46701367/211292

Answer (score 1):

The standard Java class libraries offer no way to wrap a `Reader` as an `InputStream`, but the following SO question and its answers offer some solutions.  Be careful to read the fine-print!

[How to convert a Reader to InputStream and a Writer to OutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62241/how-to-convert-a-reader-to-inputstream-and-a-writer-to-outputstream)

However, it is simpler to just stick with what you have got, (if this is just unit test code ... as it appears to be), or to replace the `StringInputStream` with a `ByteArrayInputStream` as described by @Thilo's answer.