# Kotlin equivalent of Java's String.getBytes()

Tags: kotlin

In Java, you can convert a string into an array of its constituent bytes by calling `myString.getBytes()`.

What's the equivalent of this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use the extension [`String.toByteArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-byte-array.html) - which means you will write `myString.toByteArray()`. Note it defaults to UTF-8 encoding, but you can override this by providing an additional argument.

Comment: Beware : Java's getBytes() can convert charsets (for example : myString.getBytes(Charsets.ISO_8859_1, Charsets.UTF_8) and if you want to keep this kind of conversion, you will need to use something like myString.toByteArray(Charsets.ISO_8859_1).toString(Charsets.UTF_8)

Comment: This has been renamed to `String.encodeToByteArray()`