# How to get array size in kb/mb?

Tags: android

I have such array:

```
var array: JsonArray? = JsonArray()
```

I would like to get its size in kb and mb also. I tried smth like this:

```
Singleton.array.toString().length.toString()
```

but it returns me 2 when I have empty array, so I decided that I did smth worng. Maybe someone has working way? I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970411/calculate-json-array-size-in-kb-or-mb-in-android) question.

Comment: First u need to getBytes and than convert it from there, length in your case is something totally different.

Comment: I tried to get bytes but AS can't find such method so I decided that I can't get bytes from this array

Comment: Because you are calling toString().length instead of toString().getBytes().length i guess

Comment: no, this didn't help :( unresolved reference :((((

Comment: As you are using Kotlin this should be answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46701316/kotlin-equivalent-of-javas-string-getbytes

Comment: The representation of an empty array is not an empty string, isn't it?