# Is there a simple and safe way to convert a PrintWriter into a PrintStream?

Tags: java, stream, writers

Is there a clean and simple way to convert an instance of `java.io.PrintWriter` into a `java.io.PrintStream`?

Comment: PrintWriter is intended as a replacement for PrintStream.  If you can you should use a PrintWriter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First obtain an `OutputStream` from the `Writer`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62241/how-to-convert-a-reader-to-inputstream-and-a-writer-to-outputstream)

Then pass it as argument to the `PrintStream` constructor:

```
OutputStream os = new WriterOutputStream(writer);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);
```

Update: [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) 2.0 has [`WriterOutputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/output/WriterOutputStream.html), so use it.

Comment: Unfortunately the code linked in that question is copyright, and therefore not suitable for my needs.  I'm happy to accept that I need to implement this myself.

Comment: that should not be a problem. It is "Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0". I'd bet you are using a number of thus-licensed libraries already