# Convert PrintStream to PrintWriter

Tags: java, stream

Is there any possible way of converting `PrintStream` to `PrintWriter` (or vice versa) other than using `WriterOutputStream` which is in apache common?

Comment: Can't you use wrap PrintStream in PrintWriter?

Comment: What is your objective ?

Comment: my objective is to convert printstream to print writer and NOT adding apache.jar to my code.

Comment: For the other way round, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268353/is-there-a-simple-and-safe-way-to-convert-a-printwriter-into-a-printstream

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To convert `PrintStream` to `PrintWriter`, use the constructor: [`PrintWriter(OutputStream out)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.OutputStream))

With that constructor, you risk getting the incorrect encoding, since `PrintStream` has an encoding but using [`PrintWriter(OutputStream out)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.OutputStream)) ignores that and just uses the system's default charset. If you don't want the system default, you will have to keep the encoding in a separate field or variable and use:

```
pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(myPrintStream, encoding));
```

Where `encoding` can be (for example) `"UTF-8"` or an instance of [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

Comment: You can mock `System.out.println()` via `pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);`

Comment: Better use the `OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream, Charset)` overload for UTF-8: `new OutputStreamWriter(myPrintStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. That way, you don't have to catch an UnsupportedEncodingException.