# Java Apache poi

Tags: java, apache

I am working in a project which is already developed. Now I have a task to generate excel file using `Apache poi` API.

My problem is I have PrinWriter object available instead of OutputStream.

```
workbook.write(outputStream);
```

How to tackle this situation?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268353/is-there-a-simple-and-safe-way-to-convert-a-printwriter-into-a-printstream

Comment: You would need some sort of `OutputStream` that decorates a `Writer`. There's [one in the Commons IO library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/WriterOutputStream.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
 File f=new File("c://newfolder//lijo.xls");
    PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(f);
   FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(f);
```

**for converting from one output stream to another just pass the reference value**
example to convert file to fileoutput stream

```
File file=new File("c://lijo.xls");
FileOutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: Where are you seeing a constructor on `FileOutputStream` that takes a `Writer` of any kind? There isn't one in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you work on web project you may use `ServletOutputStream` and doing something like this

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            wb.write(out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
```

Or you can use `FileInputStream`

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("MyExcel.xlsx"));
```

Comment: OP says: "My problem is I have PrinWriter object available instead of OutputStream.". So he can't use response.getOutputStream()