# how to remove html tags from URL using Jsoup and/or regular expressions Java

Tags: java, html, regex, jsoup

I need to remove HTML tags from a url using Jsoup and/or Regular Expressions in Java. 
so far I've tried a couple of stuff, using javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit and even Jsoup but I can't exchange the import java.io.FileReader; to import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL; and get it to work successfully.

What else can I do?

Here is the code I have tried**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class WebTest {
  private WebTest() {}

  public static String extractText(Reader reader) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line);
    }
    String textOnly = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString()).text();
    return textOnly;
  }




public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



  String filename = "/Users//Desktop/file4.csv";
  String urltodownload = "http://www.amazon.com";



  URL url = new URL(urltodownload);

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(filename)));

  String document = "";

  while (br.ready()) {

    String line = br.readLine();
    document += line + "\n";
    System.out.println( line );
  }  bw.close();

        String file = "/Users/Desktop/file4.csv";
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        System.out.println(WebTest.extractText(reader));
      }


}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Where's your code?

Comment: I have updated the question including the code I have tried.

Comment: And what is the problem with your code? For now it looks like you have two `main` methods and second one is outside of any class. If you have any error message post it in your question.

Comment: Assuming that you are asking about "how to change `Reader` to `InputStream`" so you could use it as argument of `Jsoup.parse` since it can only accept `URL`, `File`, `String` and `InputStream` consider visiting http://stackoverflow.com/q/62241/1393766

Comment: I just updated the code to what I just tried. This gives me the data from the URL but still without the html tags gone.

Answer (score 1):

Using Jsoup

```
public static String htmlremoved(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

Using Regex `String nohtml = YourUrlString.toString().replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");`

Comment: Why ``\\`` before `<`?

Comment: And how `<` is special here?

Comment: What do you mean (and how is that related to `replaceAll("\\<.*?>","")` part of your answer)?

Comment: `<` is not special character in regex (since `replaceAll` uses regex syntax as first argument) so it doesn't require escaping. You code should be `replaceAll("<.*?>","")` to avoid confusing others with non-required escaping. If you want to improve performance a little instead of `.*?` you can use `[^>]*` (it may be less readable but will prevent backtracking).

Comment: Sorry for late reply lost the connection and that comment was wrongly published here .. I know \\ is used to escape \ slash character .. and < is not special character .. i still need to use it sometime with old pages in HTML If i dont want to get .. things rendered like this home\ before some tag

Comment: I am kind of confused here. From "*and < is not special character*" looks like you know that `<` doesn't require escaping in regex, so I still don't see point in using ``\\`` before it. Unless you want to match `\<` literal (I don't know why would you want that) then to represent ``\`` you would need to use `"\\\\"` because ``\`` is special in regex, but also in string, so it requires double escaping (1-in regex ``\\``, 2-in String `"\\\\"`).

Comment: I've seen sometimes while generating path i end up getting like this <tag>home/user/sdir/</tag> so in non html if i don't want home/user/sdir/ but i don't want home/user/sdir look clean non html so i use \\ . It could be wrong approach and you can correct me..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so thanks to everyone who contributed. What I did that seems to have solved my problem is this. Adding the `Jsoup.parse(String).text();` to the `String line = br.readLine()`s print command like this `System.out.println( Jsoup.parse(line).text());` and this code takes out the HTML tags. Of course first you have to declare the method `public static String htmlremoved(String html) {
        return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
    }`
. You can also add the `Jsoup.parse(String).text();` code to a `bw.write`.