# Java String vs Stream

Tags: java, stream

I have a function that does something like this.

```
try {
    Process p = runtime.exec(fullCommand, null);

    BufferedReader outReaderOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = outReaderOutput.readLine();
    String output = "";

    while (line != null) {
        output += line + "\n";
        line = outReaderOutput.readLine();
    }
    return output;
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Is there a way to return Stream instead of the entire String? What would be the benefit of that?

Comment: Why are you asking if something's possible, if you don't know of what use it would be?

Comment: use `append` method of `StringBuilder` class instead `+=`

Comment: Voted to reopen this as it is certainly possible to objectively list the advantages and disadvantages of each approach without giving an opinionated answer. This is not likely to end up in a flame war; it's not a choice of implementation or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

A string is basically stored in memory; its contents are completely available at the time you receive the `String` instance. You can directly search the string or find other information - such as the length - of the string.

If you receive a `Reader` instance you don't know the size of the string, and many functions such as searching are not (directly) available. On the other hand, you don't need to store the entire string in memory.

Moreover, not all of the contents need to be available *at the time you receive the `Reader` instance*. A good example is receiving text over a socket; you may want to handle part of the contents when they are received, not after the full message is received.

The *complete* output of an application - in your example code - may also not be directly available; your method blocks until it is (i.e. until your `fullCommand` application exits).

---

If you want to return a *character stream* you can simply return the `BufferedReader` instance. If it makes sense to return a binary stream from a `Reader` most of the time, but if this *is* required then [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62257/589259).

EDIT: if you just need binary you should of course directly return `p.getInputStream()` in your example.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily return the `p.getInputStream()`
That depend on your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, you're better off returning a string *if you need the whole file at once*.

As it stands, I don't think the Java compiler can optimize this to a StringBuilder, which basically allows amortized constant time string concatenation.

You're better off using a StringBuilder like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(outReaderOutput.hasMoreLines())
{
    sb.append(outReaderOutput.readLine()).append('\n');
}
```

EDIT: wow, should not have missed that.